# How do you Export Just the .MTL file?

Tags: modeling, export

Is there a way to just export the .MTL file and not the .OBJ?

Comment: Do you need it so often that it is really necessary to find a solution other than simply deleting the OBJ file afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. You always have to save the .obj file for .mtl file to be created.

You could try modifying the exporter add-on. It's code is in Blender's installation directory(something like `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.6\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_obj\` on Windows). It's one of the simplest formats there is so the add-on is not terribly complicated and that is doable if you really need this.